# How do I check if a value already appeared in pandas df column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe of stock prices...

I wish to have a boolean column that indicates if the price had reached a certain threshold in the previous rows or not.

My output should be something like this (let's say my threshold is 100):

| index | price | bool |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 98 | False |
| 1 | 99 | False |
| 2 | 100.5 | True |
| 3 | 101 | True |
| 4 | 99 | True |
| 5 | 98 | True |

I've managed to do this with the following code but it's not efficient and takes a lot of time:

```
(df.loc[:, 'price'] > threshold).cumsum().fillna(0).gt(0)
```

Please, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a comparison and [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html):

```
threshold = 100
df['bool'] = df['price'].ge(threshold).cummax()
```

Note that it would work the other way around (although maybe less efficiently*):

```
threshold = 100
df['bool'] = df['price'].cummax().ge(threshold)
```

Output:

```
   index  price   bool
0      0   98.0  False
1      1   99.0  False
2      2  100.5   True
3      3  101.0   True
4      4   99.0   True
5      5   98.0   True
```

* indeed on a large array:

```
%%timeit
df['price'].ge(threshold).cummax()
# 193 µs ± 4.96 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%%timeit
df['price'].cummax().ge(threshold)
# 309 µs ± 4.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

##### timing

```
# setting up a dummy example with 10M rows
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'price': np.random.choice([0,1], p=[0.999,0.001], size=10_000_000)})
threshold = 0.5

## comparison

%%timeit
df['bool'] = (df.loc[:, 'price'] > threshold).cumsum().fillna(0).gt(0)
# 271 ms ± 28.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
df['bool'] = df['price'].ge(threshold).cummax()
# 109 ms ± 5.74 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each

%%timeit
df['bool'] = np.maximum.accumulate(df['price'].to_numpy()>threshold)
# 75.8 ms ± 2.86 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you,
I've tested your solution and actually both options are less efficient than my option...
I have a large-scale code that runs this line a large amount of times, so the difference is very noticeable

Comment: Surprising, could you craft a large reproducible example to test this? What about using numpy: `np.maximum.accumulate(df['price'].to_numpy()>=threshold)`?

Comment: I provided a reproducible example with 10M rows, your original solution is by far the slowest. Please provide a counter example if you can.

Comment: I don't have a neat example.
But I've tested it again and indeed tour solution works slightly faster than the solution I suggested, thanks